# How to increase a existing subnet range by incremental deployment Azure ARM template?

Tags: azure

2 subnets (A and B) each have 1 VM in them. Each VM and its resources has its own unique resource group value, which is different from the VNet/Subnet resource group value. The ARM template which was used to create the VNet and 2 subnets, gets its related ARM template parameters updated, to make the subnet CIDR of subnet B larger. Is it possible to do an incremental deployment that simply makes a subnet larger?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless something is assigned to the subnet. You cant alter a subnet if something is assigned to it